# Symfony 4 , Identify between anonymous user and user whose session has been killed by inactivity

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Is there a way to identify whether a user is totally anonymous or is a user whose session has been expired because of inactivity from the controller. 
I tried  `$this->get('session');` but found out it is not very reliable.

Helpful points.

- The user hasn't opt in for remember me.
- The user has been logged out automatically after a period of inactivity.

My objective was to determine if its possible whether the current user was logged out because of inactivity or is just a totally pure anonomyous user.

My security.yaml file

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\MoUser:
        algorithm: bcrypt
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:

    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\MoUser
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        provider: our_db_provider
        simple_form:
            authenticator: App\Security\OfmAuthenticator
            check_path: app_security_login
            login_path: app_security_login
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        remember_me:
            secret: '%kernel.secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 #1 week in seconds
            path: /
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login
```

Comment: Can you give us more details about your security.yaml firewall configuration and about what you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i have added my security.yaml in my post

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible through the session only: if the session is killed due to a timeout, there is exactly no more information available, as obviously the session is killed ;)

What you could try is something like a "remember me"-cookie (see the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html) for that feature). Even it the session expires, the cookie can live longer and help to login the user again without asking for the credentials